# Dynamically-Allocated Implementation-Class std::async-ing its Member

Tags: multithreading, c++11, asynchronous, shared-ptr

Consider an operation with a standard asynchronous interface:

```
std::future<void> op();
```

Internally, `op` needs to perform a (variable) number of asynchronous operations to complete; the number of these operations is finite but unbounded, and depends on the results of the previous asynchronous operations.

Here's a (bad) attempt:

```
/* An object of this class will store the shared execution state in the members;
*    the asynchronous op is its member. */
class shared
{
private:
    // shared state

private:
    // Actually does some operation (asynchronously).
    void do_op()
    {
        ...
        // Might need to launch more ops.
        if(...)
            launch_next_ops();
    }

public:
    // Launches next ops
    void launch_next_ops()
    {
        ...
        std::async(&shared::do_op, this);
    }
}

std::future<void> op()
{
    shared s;
    s.launch_next_ops();
    // Return some future of s used for the entire operation.
    ...
    // s destructed - delayed BOOM!
};
```

The problem, of course, is that `s` goes out of scope, so later methods will not work.

To amend this, here are the changes:

```
class shared : public std::enable_shared_from_this<shared> 
{
private:
    /* The member now takes a shared pointer to itself; hopefully 
    *    this will keep it alive. */
    void do_op(std::shared_ptr<shared> p); // [*]

    void launch_next_ops()
    {
        ...
        std::async(&shared::do_op, this, shared_from_this());
    }
}

std::future<void> op()
{
    std::shared_ptr<shared> s{new shared{}};
    s->launch_next_ops();
    ...
};
```

(Asides from the weirdness of an object calling its method with a shared pointer to itself, )the problem is with the line marked `[*]`. The compiler (correctly) warns that it's an unused variable.

Of course, it's possible to fool it somehow, but is this an indication of a  fundamental problem? Is there any chance the compiler will optimize away the argument and leave the method with a dead object? Is there a better alternative to this entire scheme? I don't find the resulting code the most intuitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the compiler will not optimize away the argument. Indeed, that's irrelevant as the lifetime extension comes from `shared_from_this()` being bound by decay-copy (**[thread.decaycopy]**) into the result of the call to `std::async` (**[futures.async]**/3).

If you want to avoid the warning of an unused argument, just leave it unnamed; compilers that warn on unused arguments will not warn on unused unnamed arguments.

An alternative is to make `do_op` `static`, meaning that you *have to* use its `shared_ptr` argument; this also addresses the duplication between `this` and `shared_from_this`. Since this is fairly cumbersome, you might want to use a lambda to convert `shared_from_this` to a `this` pointer:

```
std::async([](std::shared_ptr<shared> const& self){ self->do_op(); }, shared_from_this());
```

If you can use C++14 init-captures this becomes even simpler:

```
std::async([self = shared_from_this()]{ self->do_op(); });
```

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer! Leaving the argument unnamed is what I was doing, and am pleased that it's legal.